# ROSjava subscriber

Tags: ros, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have problem with subscriber, when I run my **android application** a see in LogCat that "Unable to resolve host "ROS": No address associated with hostname".

I have set in .bashrc

> ROS_IP=10.0.0.139 ,
> ROS_HOSTNAME=10.0.0.139 ,
> ROS_MASTER_URI=http:// 10.0.0.139:11311

In file /etc/hosts

> 127.0.0.1 localhost ,
> 127.0.1.1 ROS

and in file /etc/hostname

> ROS

If I create publisher it's all OK, but subscriber is still wrong.
Do you know where is problem ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54399/rosjava-subscriber/) by [LeopoldPodmolík](https://answers.ros.org/users/3844/leopoldpodmol%C3%ADk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2013-02-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved.

The problem was in file *.bashrc*, where I had only

> ROS_IP=10.0.0.139

when I write full command

> export ROS_IP=10.0.0.139

all will be OK. I recognise by this code in shell

> python -c "import roslib.network; print roslib.network.get_address_override()"

because return NONE, what was wrong ...

---

Originally posted by [LeopoldPodmolík](https://answers.ros.org/users/3844/leopoldpodmol%C3%ADk/) with karma: 66 on 2013-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1